# Combine two bar plots into one graph

Tags: graph, stata

I have this dataset:

```
clear

input gender salary education child
1 5000 2000 2100
0 4000 2200 2300
1 4000 3220 3300
0 5660 4500 3200
1 4333 3200 2190
1 6550 4370 1990
0 4330 1900 3200
1 3500 2100 4600
1 5320 4100 3499
1 5100 2100 3100
end
```

The command below produces the following graph:

[image]

How can I put everything in one graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put everything in one graph the following will work:

```
graph bar salary education child, over(gender)
```

[image]

Alternatively:

```
separate salary, by(gender)
separate education, by(gender)
separate child, by(gender)

graph bar salary? education? child?, bargap(10)
```

[image]

You can also play with the *barlook* options of `graph bar` to further tweak the 
results:

```
graph bar salary? education? child?, bargap(10) ///
                                     bar(1, color(ebblue)) ///
                                     bar(2, color(ebblue)) ///
                                     bar(3, color(red)) ///
                                     bar(4, color(red)) ///
                                     bar(5, color(green)) ///
                                     bar(6, color(green)) ///
                                     legend(off)
```

[image]